# What improvements can be made to this set of codes to generate solutions to this problem?

Tags: pari, pari-gp

Aside from increasing the ranges of y  which is between -1000 to 1000, [what other improvements should I make to these codes so that when I run it on any pari gp compiler online, it returns very valid answers?](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VVJLboMwEFW3OcWUSoltYgUblyJF7po7RCHKIrQIVBBNBabqSbrJpuqdeo1eoGM-DXgxHvvNe2809ud3eazSw1N5uXy9nRMe_tz8vi8gKSpiNBee562hiwvAFWl4NuWpOuV5dTyXRfpyfiVEBFIqd1XHPg-kYquaGe7jFktmYukKqUJMfNfvoFghaOKAbgIrHT_QbadtLVMt1nAX9WYArYZol-53cr8dbtKEtI_Ykt21TvICSS0d6wHqgSH-GQCZBoK9dL0Z13oruhFKXStQLRvVsokaQINcy5C8Ro7cTiAkNSOpmZF67Fb3fQrJGutuVVjjGkZwFvxeUo4I2nqwXAJvcVAjgNUyDFnGUN-bCwOUFQ6dOMRpnDU4xobWhsyhDp3V0unxmo_ZAGOki4_-7YcvMH6FPw)

When I ran these codes from within the ranges of -1000 to 1000 and from to -10000 to 10000, it returned some answers but nothing beyond these ranges.  Though I am aware that between ranges of y: -10^12 to 10^12 for instance, there are some desirable solutions, like when y = 22 741 480 906, I do not know what else to do to arrive at such results systematically aside from increasing ranges of y as mentioned above.

```
{
 for(y=-1000, 1000,
    H= hyperellratpoints((16224+'w^3-624*'w*y-3*'w^2*y^2+1248*y^3+3*'w*y^4-3*y^6)/6, 10^7);
    for(i=1, #H,
      z= H[i][2];
      if(z>0, if(z==floor(z),
        w= H[i][1];
        k= (w^2-624*y+3*y^4)/144;
        if(k==floor(k),
          x= (3*y^2-w)/12;
          if(x==floor(x),
            if(x!=0, if(12*x^2-6*y^2*x+y*(y^3-52)-12*k==0 && -z^2+(y^3-52)^2-288*k*x==0,
              print("("x", "y", "z", "k")")
            ))
          )
        )
      ))
    )
 )
}
```

Comment: Your for-loop syntax is not correct. Is that really supposed to be C code?

Comment: there was an omission of a curly bracket in the beginning which I have corrected.

Comment: There is no way this compiled as C code. for loop has 3 sections separated by `;` inside the parenthesis.  `#H` is not valid expression. We expect you to put more effort into your problem before asking us for help.

Comment: @AllanWind  I only included c in the tags because the home website of pari gp describes pari as a c library and I thought it useful to include it in the tags. https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a cursory look at your code, it seems you are looking at integer solutions of an equation `6*z^2 = P(y,w)` for some explicit polynomial `P` with integer coefficients, and you further require two auxiliary quantities to be integral. You're doing this by trying all integral values of `y` in a certain range, computing for each such `y` all rational solutions of bounded height for the equation `z^2=P/6`, then filtering out using various tests (in particular `z > 0`).

To answer your main question: there's no ready-made function for finding integer points on general surfaces in PARI/GP.

What you can and should do is

1. simplify the problem arithmetically as much as possible. For instance if `y`,`w` and `x = (3y^2-w)/12` are integral, then 3 divides `w = 3W` and you now want `x = (y^2 - W) / 4` to be integral which implies that 'y', 'w' and 'W' share the same parity (and in fact `4 | W` when even, congruent to 1 mod 4 otherwise).

You may want to split the problem in two cases at this point: `y` odd or even, etc. Once done as much as possible, use the new variables. All integrality tests can then be removed: if you have integral solutions in the new variables, they will automatically satisfy the divisibility conditions (and divisions by constants simplify).

2. I'm not sure why you're checking `12*x^2-6*y^2*x+y*(y^3-52)-12*k==0` and `-z^2+(y^3-52)^2-288*k*x==0` as both follow formally from the definitions of `k` and `x`, hence are always true.
3. the special case `x = 0` (or `y = 3*w^2`) provides trivial solutions since your equation becomes `z = |y^3 - 52|` (I understand you're excluding those).
4. It all boils down to finding integral solutions of an equation `a^2 = Q(b,c)` where everybody in sight is integral. You will either have to use more about the geometry of the surface (for instance understand why `x = 0` leads to all these trivial solutions), or simply loop over `b,c` integral in some range and check whether the result is a square. This test is exceedingly fast and you can certainly check about 10^16 pairs `(b,c)` in reasonable time on a single computer. (Make that 10^20 if you have access to a computing cluster.)

A final remark: to test whether `x` is an integer in PARI/GP (which is no longer needed in the version I recommend) use either `type(x) == "t_INT"` or `denominator(x) == 1` if you already know that `x` is a rational number.

Comment: While I do not have access to a computing cluster, what about Google Cloud computing, would I then be able to go 10^20 and above?

Comment: You would need to rewrite the program along the above lines, then time it on a restricted sample and extrapolate. On my old general purpose laptop, letting PARI-GP check whether 10^8 random 64 bit integers are squares requires less than 4.5s. Testing for 10^20 would require approximately 160000 years. Divide that by the number of available cores. As it turns out, my estimate above for a single computer was somewhat optimistic using PARI-GP: make that 10^14 (or change the meaning of "reasonable").